# How to create a list with multiple datatypes (characters as well as integers) using loop (both for and while loop) in python .

Tags: python, list, types

I am trying to create a list with multiple datatypes (characters as well as integers) using loop (both for and while loop).

The code snippet using while loop is as follows:-

```
my_list=[]
item=0
while item!=5:
    item=int(input("""Enter the number to create the list(To discontinue enter 5): """))
    my_list.append(item)

print("The list created is: ",my_list)
length=len(my_list)
```

Code snippet using for loop:-

```
list=[]
#Creating the list

count=int(input("Set the length of list as 7, Enter 7: "))
for i in range(count):
    item=int(input("Enter the element: "))
    list.append(item)

    if (count-i==2):
        last_item=int(input("Enter the 7th element:"))
        list.append(last_item)
        break

print("\nThe list created is: ",list)
```

My code can create list either with integer or string only. I am unable to mix the datatype(i.e. both integer and string in same list).
Please suggest what modification is needed to be done in my code.

Also, I want to know one more thing,that using while loop we can discontinue the execution.How it can be done when there are multiple datatype elements in list.

Comment: `[1, '2', '3', 4]` Done.

Comment: You getting any errors ?

Comment: But here 2 and 3 will be treated as string??? correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I want my list to be something like this:- list=[123,'abc','def',456,'xyz',999].Is it possible?

Comment: Well they're not going to be treated as *lollipops*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list=[]
item=0
while item!="5":
    item=raw_input("""Enter the number to create the list(To discontinue enter 5): """)


    if item.isdigit():
          my_list.append(int(item))

    else:
          my_list.append(item)



print("The list created is: ",my_list)
```

Comment: this way you can print both characters and integer.Your mistake was to use int with input function as it will give error .I am taking input as string and then checking whether that string is integer or character.Execution will end with 5 only i am not changing structure of your program,though there are many good ways to do that

Comment: Thanks Sir, It worked. But I had to modify the "raw_input" to "input". Because i was getting following error:- item=raw_input("""Enter the number to create the list(To discontinue enter 5): """)
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: you must be using python 3. i executed on python 2 .If you like my answer please mark it